# Seeing the output of my program

Tags: c, compiler-construction, return

I am having a problem with a program of mine, as I cannot see the output display.  Using a Dev C++ compiler to compile my C program, I debug it to see the output.  However my program immediately terminates, so I can't see the output properly.

I ended my program with return 0, and Aldo tried getch(), but even with both endings my program terminates quick.

I want to know if my program endings are wrong, and if so what is the correct way to end a program?

Comment: please post your code. with out your code we did not get which is causing this scenario ...!

Comment: Try `getchar()` instead of `getch()`

Comment: Did you found some thing like this **undefined reference to `getch'** ,this is because of getch is not there in standard C ,this is a Borland function. use **getchar()**.

Comment: Using Dev C++ for *anything*, much less for C-development, seems a bit masochistic. That aside, without seeing code, all I can offer is "Yes, you're likely doing something wrong." In other words, removing the three words in the middle of your question title will *greatly* enhance our ability to answer it.

Comment: You have to post your program, because we cannot figure out what is going on. For example, the right answer to your question could depend on the type of input/output sentences that you are using in your program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need the window stop to view the output, is it right?

if yes, include this library

```
#include <stdlib.h>
```

then add this line at the end of code:

```
system("PAUSE");
```

e.g

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
/* do/print some thing*/
system("PAUSE");

}
```